# Define multiple page styles with fancyhdr (also multiple plain)

Tags: fancyhdr

Is it possible to define multiple page style using fancyhdr package, for toc and for the document, setting also in a different mode the plain pages for toc and the plain pages for the document.

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{lastpage}

\fancypagestyle{document}{%
  \fancyhf{}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage\ |\ \pageref{LastPage}}
}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage\ |\ \pageref{LastPage}}
}

\fancypagestyle{tocstyle}{%
  \fancyhf{}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
}

\begin{document}\sloppy
    
    \pagenumbering{Roman}
    \pagestyle{tocstyle}
    \tableofcontents
    \listoffigures
    \listoftables  
    \clearpage 
    
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
    \pagestyle{document}
    
    \Blinddocument
    \Blinddocument
    \Blinddocument
    \Blinddocument
    \Blinddocument
    \Blinddocument
    \Blinddocument
    \Blinddocument
    \Blinddocument
    \Blinddocument
    
\end{document}
```

The document is formatted well, but not the toc, because plain pages of the toc are affected by having the same arrangement of the document pages.

Is there a way to define a complete page style for different document sections, or to suppress the fact of having "plain" pages?

Answer (score 1):

The first pages of ToC, LoF, LoT is always pagestyle `plain`, like all other first chapter pages. This causes the chosen page style `tocstyle` not to be effective on these first pages.

**Update: Added a solution with the `plain` definitions inside the other pagestyles.**

1. One solution this would be to redefine `plain` to be the same as `tocstyle` before the ToC etc. and then redefine it to be the desired `plain` style for the document after the `\clearpage` that separates these ToC pages from the main document. A comprehensive way to do this would be to include the `\fancypagestyle{plain}...` inside the other `\fancypagestyle` definitions, thereby bundling them up with these page styles. See **Solution 1**.
2. Another way is to inject an additional `\thispagestyle{tocstyle}` in the ToC, LoF and LoT with commands like

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\thispagestyle{tocstyle}}
```

This needs an additional LaTeX run to get effectuated. See **Solution 2**.

Here are the complete solutions with these ideas. For demonstration purposes I have added the name of the page style in the left footer so that you can clearly see where it comes from.

**Solution 1:**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{lastpage}

\fancypagestyle{document}{%
  \fancyhf{}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage\ |\ \pageref{LastPage}}
  \fancyfoot[L]{document}
  \fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \fancyhf{}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage\ |\ \pageref{LastPage}}
    \fancyfoot[L]{plain-document}
  }
}

\fancypagestyle{tocstyle}{%
  \fancyhf{}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
  \fancyfoot[L]{tocstyle}
  % Make plain pagestyle the same as tocstyle
  % The optional argument needs fancyhdr version 4.0 or later.
  % Otherwise you have to copy all the definitions from tocstyle.
  \fancypagestyle{plain}[tocstyle]{\fancyfoot[L]{plain-tocstyle}} 
}

\begin{document}\sloppy
    \pagenumbering{Roman}
    \pagestyle{tocstyle}
    \tableofcontents
    \listoffigures
    \listoftables  
    \clearpage 
    
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
    \pagestyle{document}
    
    \Blinddocument
    \Blinddocument
    \Blinddocument
    \Blinddocument
    \Blinddocument
    \Blinddocument
    \Blinddocument
    \Blinddocument
    \Blinddocument
    \Blinddocument
    
\end{document}
```

**Solution 2:**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{lastpage}

\fancypagestyle{document}{%
  \fancyhf{}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage\ |\ \pageref{LastPage}}
  \fancyfoot[L]{document}
}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage\ |\ \pageref{LastPage}}
  \fancyfoot[L]{plain}
}

\fancypagestyle{tocstyle}{%
  \fancyhf{}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
  \fancyfoot[L]{tocstyle}
}

\begin{document}\sloppy
    \pagenumbering{Roman}
    \pagestyle{tocstyle}
    \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\thispagestyle{tocstyle}}
    \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\thispagestyle{tocstyle}}
    \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\thispagestyle{tocstyle}}
    \tableofcontents
    \listoffigures
    \listoftables  
    \clearpage 
    
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
    \pagestyle{document}
    
    \Blinddocument
    \Blinddocument
    \Blinddocument
    \Blinddocument
    \Blinddocument
    \Blinddocument
    \Blinddocument
    \Blinddocument
    \Blinddocument
    \Blinddocument
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Pieter. My undestanding is that I can define multiple page style but I can have only one plain style at time. 

Normally I like to define the structure of my documents in a separated file (as well as foot notes, captions, etc.) but in this case the only chance I have is to inject the style as you shown me or redefine plain style when it is needed. 

Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, you can have only one `plain` page style at a time. That applies also to other page styles. However, you can put the `\fancypagestyle{plain}{....}` inside the other `\fancypagestyle` definitions, thereby "bundling them up".

Comment: Dear @Pieter your last comment saved my day! it was exactly what I was looking for: defining and embedding a plain page style for each defined page style. I change my code putting every customized `\fancypagestyle{plain}{...}` inside every`\fancypagestyle` definitions as you suggested me. I owe you.

Comment: I will update my answer to include this solution (and I am going to put this in the manual too).

Comment: Surely adding the plain style inside a custom page style definition is more redundant (because I think that usually it is needed to replicate the normal page style also for plain pages) but once you put your layout definition in a separated files, I guess the main code is more readable and simpler (anyway, injecting the style in toc, tof and tot is not a big deal)